# Manipulating Tumblr's default iframe controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, tumblr

Is there any way I can manipulate the tumblr controls? They are quite ugly and gray. I want to know if there is any way to add `iframe#tumblr_controls {display:none;}` to my CSS and recreate all the controls with the same functionality but with a different look. [Tumblr controls (iFrame)](http://www.tumblr.com/dashboard/iframe?10&src=http%3A%2F%2F-respawn.tumblr.com%2F&lang=en_US&name=-respawn)

Comment: sorry, unable to respond asap, otherwise i would

Comment: This isn't the answer you are going to appreciate, but its not possible to manipulate cross-domain elements via an iframe.  The only way to be able to do this is using  JSONP with iframes... http://snaggled.github.com/2010/04/08/Understanding-cross-domain-javascript.html

Comment: @mkoryak What do you mean? :S

Comment: @Downpour046 I know that. I want to hide the tumblr controls, and get the scripts that make the iframe function, and then create NEW elements with my own styles and apply the scripts. Basically, I just want to restyle the controls.

Comment: The only thing you can manipulate is the iframe itself, not the contents within the iframe.  What language are you using?  You (may) be able to use PHP or your coding language to include the file instead of using an iframe?

Comment: The link in your question - says page not found. Please update the link so I have a better understanding

Comment: Yes, you can set `iframe#tumblr_controls {display:none;}` and make your own in your own `div` area in the `body` by utilizing the Tumblr curly bracket tags. It'll take me a little bit to ready some working code, but I understand what you're trying to do and I see no reason why you shouldn't be able to make it work.

Comment: Please note, however, that you won't be able to create the exact same functionality because Tumblr does not provide any documented source code for you to change the display of things depending on whether or not the person is following you _unless_ you have API information and the permission to fully access the blog of the person browsing yours. Basically, what I'm saying is that you can change the controls and have them display different things on different types of pages but if you, say, display a Follow link? It's going to show up even if they're already following you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's fairly easy to replace all the functionality. As you suggested, you can hide Tumblr's default with:

```
#tumblr_controls {display:none;}
```

On index pages, you need Dashboard, Follow, and Email. You can't determine if you need Unfollow, but always showing Follow shouldn't be too bad.

Dashboard URL:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/dashboard
```

Follow URL:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/follow/<blogname>
```

Email URL:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/send/<blogname>?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2F<blogname>.tumblr.com%2F
```

On permalink pages you also need Reblog and Like. These are a little more difficult but I have a sample here: http://like-button.tumblr.com/

Reblog uses an undocumented variable, `{ReblogURL}`. You simply make it the the `href` of a link:

```html
<a href="{ReblogURL}">reblog</a>
```

To add Like functionality, you use the following URL and set it as the `src` attribute of an invisible `<iframe>`:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/<command>/<oauthId>?id=<postId>
```

- `<command>`: `like` or `unlike`
- `<oauthId>`: last eight characters of `{ReblogURL}`
- `<postId>`: `{PostID}`

Example:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/like/fGKvAJgQ?id=16664837215
```

You need to put both variables, `{ReblogURL}` and `{PostID}`, into your `{block:Posts}` block. Then use script to build the URL and set the `src`.

```js
$( document ).on( 'click', '.like', function ( event ) {

event.preventDefault();

var command = $( this ).hasClass( 'liked' ) ? 'unlike' : 'like',
    post = $( this ).closest( '.post' ),
    oauth = post.find( '.reblog' ).attr( 'href' ).slice( -8 ),
    id = post.attr( 'id' ),
    likeUrl = 'http://www.tumblr.com/' + command + '/' + oauth + '?id=' + id;

$( '#like-it' ).attr( 'src', likeUrl );
$( this ).toggleClass( 'liked' );

} );
```

```html
{block:Posts}
<article id="{PostID}">
<a href="{ReblogURL}" class="reblog">reblog</a>
<a href="#" class="like">like</a>
</article>
{/block:Posts}

<iframe id="like-it"></iframe>
```

```css
#like-it {
    display: none;
}

.liked, .like:hover {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's different now. Just add

```
#iframe_controls { display:none; }
```

To the CSS (inside  tag of 'Edit HTML').